# Can NP-complete language be in $mP/poly$?

Tags: circuit-complexity, np-complete, monotone

Can NP-complete language be in monotone $P/poly$?

Comment: Isn't it unlikely since otherwise we would have $NP \subseteq P/poly$ which would imply $PH = \Sigma_2$ by Karp-Lipton Theorem?

Comment: Can we say something stronger, based on Razborov,Alon,Boppana result that SAT cannot be in mP\poly?

The question is can we deduce from SAT$\notin$ mP/poly, that any NP-complete language is outside of mP/poly?

Comment: SAT is not a monotone language, hence it is trivially outside mP/poly. The Razborov/Alon–Boppana results state that certain *monotone* NP languages (Clique, or the dual of Colourability) are outside mP/poly. But yes, I think the question whether we can *unconditionally* (or at least, under a weaker assumption than $\mathrm{NP\nsubseteq P/poly}$) prove at the moment that no NP-complete language is in mP/poly is interesting. (This does not follow automatically from Alon–Boppana, as polynomial-time reductions between monotone NP-complete languages may not preserve monotone circuit size.)

Comment: I should perhaps point out that the Razborov/Alon–Boppana result is not so much about the complexity of NP-complete problems, but rather about the difference between monotone and non-monotone circuits: the lower bound applies to all functions separating graphs with clique size $k+1$ from $k$-colourable graphs where $k=\sqrt n$ or so, and as shown by Tardos, there is a *polynomial-time* monotone function that fits the bill.